# What happens when you define an empty default constructor?

Tags: c++

I have searched previous questions, and have not found a satisfying answer to my question:

If I define an empty default constructor for a class, as for example

```
class my_class{
public:
    myclass(){}
private:
    int a;
    int* b;
    std::vector<int> c;
}
```

my understanding is that if I define an object using the default constructor, say

```
my_class my_object;
```

then my_object.a will be a random value, the pointer my_object.b will also be a random value, however the vector c will be a well-behaved, empty vector.

In other words, the default constructor of c is called while the default constructors of a and b is not. Am I understanding this correctly? What is the reason for this?

Thank you!

Comment: Plain old datatypes (PODs) do not have constructors.

Comment: I'm being a bit pedantic here because I have seen people attempt to use uninitialized values as a random number generator. Better terms for the state and contents of a and b are uninitialized and undefined, respectively. Random doesn't work, but cause the contents are not random. They may be unbelievably predictable, for example a canary value like DEADBEEF. A nice C++ implementation may set them to 0 for you. The point is you can't count on any behaviour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`a` and `b` have non-class types, meaning that they have no constructors at all. Otherwise, your description is correct: `my_object.a` and `my_object.b` will have indeterminate values, while `my_object.c` will be properly constructed.

As for why... by writing a user-defined constructor and not mentioning `a` and `b` in the initializer list (and not using C++11 in-class member initializers) you explicitly asked the compiler to leave these members uninitialized.

Note that if your class did not have a user-defined constructor, you'd be able to control the initial values of `my_object.a` and `my_object.b` from outside, by specifying initializers at the point of object declaration

```
my_class my_object1;
// Garbage in `my_object1.a` and `my_object1.b`

my_class my_object2{};
// Zero in `my_object2.a` and null pointer in `my_object2.b`
```

But when you wrote your own default constructor, you effectively told the compiler that you want to "override" this initialization behavior and do everything yourself.

Comment: It's also good to note the difference between `object o = object()` and `object o`; for POD types (no constructor), the former will default-initialize all members, even the ones without constructors (setting their bits to 0). Similarly, in your constructor's initializer list you could write `: a(), b()` which would also default-initialize `a` and `b` to 0.

Comment: Ok, that answers it. I guess my confusion came from the fact that the implicit default constructor (defined if none is explicitly defined) does set int variables to 0 and pointer types to NULL, so I was thinking of those null initializations as a kind of constructor.

Comment: @user3208430: The implicit default constructor does no such thing -- only if you call it with `()`/`{}` will the members be default initialized. You can test this with `new object` vs `new object()`.

Comment: @user3208430: `int` variables and pointer variables do not have implicit default constructors. It is true that `int i = int();` or `int i{};` initializes `i` to zero, but this initialization process does not involve any constructors.

Comment: @Cameron: Thanks for that information, I didn't know that. In the case of an implicit constructor for my_class, what if an object of my_class is itself a member of another class, which is then instantiated by its own default constructor, would a and b then be zero initialized?

Comment: @user3208430: It will depend on the constructor of the enveloping class in pretty much the same way. If the enveloping class has a user-defined constructor that doesn't bother to initialize that inner `my_class` member, `a` and `b` will end up with garbage.

Comment: @AnT: Let's say that we're using the enveloping class' implicit default constructor. Then the my_class object would be constructed using its default constructor (implicit one), with a and b being zero initialized, right?

Comment: It might be worth noting in the answer that this distinction between a and b on the one hand and c on the other hand is called "trivial" in the spec; a and b are trivial, and c is not. Or to zoom in further, a and b are trivially constructible, c is not. "trivial" is different from both POD and primitive, which many people incorrectly cite as the criteria to get this differing behavior.

Comment: @Cameron "only if you call it with ()/{} will the members be default initialized." - they're *value-initialized*. They're default-initialized in the case of no `()` or `{}`, and said-initialization for those is to do... nothing.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Oops, thanks for correcting my terminology.

Answer (score 2):

Since `a` and `b` are not objects but primitive datatypes, there is no constructor to call.  In contrast, `c` is an object, so its default constructor is called.

Comment: `a` and `b` will be objects once a `myclass` is instantiated.

Comment: @juanchopanza No they aren't.  Not every variable is an object in C++.  Anything of a primitive type (int, char, long, short, any pointer, bool, etc) is not an object.

Comment: @GabeSechan Yes, they are. You are quite mistaken.

Comment: @juanchopanza No they aren't.  THey're primitives.  The term object is reserved for classes, structs, and unions.  Please study up on C++.

Comment: @GabeSechan You really don't have a clue, do you? These things are called objects in C++. Your ignorance is astounding.

Comment: @juanchopanza No, they aren't.  Primitives are not objects.

Comment: Enough sniping, folks. Where in the standard does it refer to these "objects" you speak of?

Comment: @Cameron In **1.8 The C++ object model [intro.object]**. "An *object* is a region of storage". There is no distinction between built-ins and user-defined types.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Right then. Thanks. Not used very much in everyday terms though :-)

Comment: @Cameron Still, a lot of the standard wouldn't make any sense if "object" were restricted to user defined types. So after a while in C++, one gets used to that terminology.

Comment: @juanchopanza: On the contrary, after a while with the C++ *standard* one gets used to it ;-) I've used C++ for years without bothering about the non-OOP definition of object. (I vaguely recall it might have come up once or twice.) You can tell I don't peruse sections of the standard very often.

Comment: @Cameron Ha, that OOP thing. You probably think a `struct` is very different to a `class` too ;-)

Comment: @juanchopanza: Not at all. It's possible to be proficient in C++ without reading the standard (although of course it comes in handy every now and then).